# Build J2Me App programatically from ASP Website

Tags: java-me, midlet

I am having this peculiar problem in hand. I have newly developed J2Me App Midlet, now I want to give this App to the user as a download from my website. I want to build the application programmatically as user clicks the link to download it, It is so because there is a set variable data, I want to hard code inside J2Me App, depending upon the user profile. I can not  make sets of J2Me App ready to download as this would be too huge a task.

Can any one tell me how this can be achieved ?

The website is ASP based website.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding the data in the class file, why don't you use a jad file property and just generate the JAD File Property while the user download the application. Inside the MIDlet you can just refer to the property using MIDlet.getAppProperty() method to read that JAD property.

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay, Seems Interesting...But if after some time the user changes his/her data on server and i want to incorporate the changed data on his/her mobile device. Can i just download the JAD file instead of building and downloading entire JAR file.

Comment: For the first time, you can use the initial values from the JAD once the user changes those values, you can store them in the RMS and then update it to the server where it can store it in some db or something, thereby avoiding the need to download the app again. Also it is not a right design or user experience to ask the user to download the application again and again for some changes to some property that might happen during the course of the user using the application.